# Firebase On click con envio de parametros

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

estoy trabajando hace poco con firebase y js y tengo una duda: Tengo por un lado el .html y por otro un .js el tema que en el js quiero hacer un boton para poder abrir el detalle de un objeto y que al hacer click este pase su id lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

function listarMisPrestamos(res){

```
var pag = "detalle.html"
var contenido="<table class='table'>";

contenido+="<thead>";
contenido+="<tr>";
contenido+="<td>Interno</td>";
contenido+="<td>Domino</td>";
contenido+="<td>Acciones</td>";

contenido+="</tr>";

contenido+="</thead>";
contenido+="<tbody>";

res.forEach(el=>{
    var fila= el.data();
    contenido+="<tr>";
    contenido+="<td>"+fila.interno+"</td>";
    contenido+="<td>"+fila.dominio+"</td>";
    contenido+="<td>";
    
    ACA VA EL BOTON

    contenido+="<input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' value='Ver Detalle' onclick='document.location.href =((\""+pag+"\"),(\""+el.id+"\"))' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' />";


    contenido+="</td>";
    contenido+="</tr>";

});

contenido+="</tbody>";
contenido+="</table>";

document.getElementById("divListUnidades").innerHTML=contenido;
```

}

alguna forma de poder enviar en el onclick a detalle.html y como envio su id para mostrarlo uso +el.id+ y despues como hago para recuperarlo en la otra pagina.

muchas gracias

Comment: Huy, compañero, le recomiendo mejor usar un framework de frontend, ya sea Jquery, React, Vuew o algo que se le parezca... mantener ese código creado así se podría convertir en una pesadilla. Aún así, le recomiendo crear mejor una funcion para manejar el onclick de cada boton

Comment: que funcion podria emplear para reemplazar en onclick ? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Así puede añadir un evento click a cada uno de los botones con una misma función... dentro de esa función tiene el elemento completo y puede hacer con el lo que desee.

```js
let contenido = "";
let pag = "Otrapagina.html";

const onClick = (elem) => {
  return () => alert(`hizo click en el botón con id ${elem.id} y other ${elem.other}`);
}

const elements = [
  { id: 1, other: "a" },
  { id: 2, other: "b" },
  { id: 3, other: "c" },
  { id: 4, other: "d" },
  { id: 5, other: "e" },

];

for(elem of elements) {
contenido+=`<div><input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' value='Boton con Id = ${elem.id}' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' id='btn${elem.id}' /></div>` ;
}

//Escribe los botones en el dom
document.write(contenido);

//Obtiene una referencia a ellos y les asinga el evento
for(elem of elements) {
   const domElem = document.querySelector("#btn"+elem.id);
   domElem.addEventListener("click", onClick(elem));
}
```